# Correct Word Usage: Parametra vs Parameters

Tags: grammatical-number, greek

I am used to referring to '*parametra*' instead of '*parameters*', however, trying to justify it this morning, I was stumped. Lots of articles say that '*parameters*' is the only correct plural; following the original Greek, '*parametroi*' should be the correct word usage.

However, a quick search on [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parametra%2Cparameters%2Cparametroi&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cparametra%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BParametra%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bparametra%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cparameters%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bparameters%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BParameters%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPARAMETERS%3B%2Cc0) found that '*parametroi*' has no references at all, and that '*parametra*' used to be used - fairly commonly [in the '20's and '50's (and another peak in the '80's)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parametra&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cparametra%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BParametra%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bparametra%3B%2Cc0), but isn't that common any more. '*Parameters*' has always been used more than the alternatives.

Is '*parametra*' correct, and if so, what is the derivation that leads to it? If it is not correct, what is the proper technical plural of '*parameter*', and also, what is the source for the uncommon usage of '*parametra*'?

Comment: There are no usage examples for Parametra in Ngram

Comment: This is really an exercise in graph-reading. Look at how many zeroes there are on the vertical scale of that Ngram.  [If you add "parameters"to the list](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parametra%2Cparameters&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cparametra%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BParametra%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bparametra%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cparameters%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bparameters%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BParameters%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPARAMETERS%3B%2Cc0), you will see that is has so dominated "parametera" that it makes the latter insignificant.

Comment: I have never, in a half-century of technical activities, read or heard "parametera" (until now).

Comment: And I don't find *any* definitions of "parametra" in online English dictionaries.

Comment: And your Ngram search only finds the word once in an English document (and that appears to be a quote of sorts).

Comment: @Spencer: I'm not certain where you see the Ngram information on actual usages; it is my first time playing around with it though. Surely the 3E-8 it has in recent years comes from some usage of the word? And that is one of the graphs I looked at; in general though, something that is common may not be necessarily correct, hence the question.

Comment: @gtkscrk An incorrect thing that is common wouldn't be hundreds of times more frequent than the correct thing. Please click on the link in my comment to see what I mean.

Comment: Click on the word *parametra* at the bottom of either Ngram. All the examples on the first pages of the returns are in languages other than English, except for one which uses *Parametra*

Comment: "Parametra" seems to be used in English in some cases in gynaecological contexts (e.g. [Practical Gynaecological Ultrasound](https://books.google.com/books?id=kXUgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&dq=%22parametra%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsh-ul2LLQAhULxoMKHVJTDc44ChDoAQhJMAk#v=onepage&q=%22parametra%22&f=false)), but after more research, it seems to me that this is a typo for "[parametria](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/parametrium)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Google Books search for *parametra*](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=parametra&num=10) yields 27 confirmed matches, of which only a handful are in English. Most of the results seem to be in Russian and other Slavic languages. Of the arguably English matches for *parametra*, one is the (Linnean system) genus name of a crinoid ([*Parametra granulata*](https://books.google.com/books?id=F7YPAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA34&dq=parametra&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju6_2z8LLQAhVG4mMKHWQpBG84ChDoAQgoMAM#v=onepage&q=parametra&f=false)), two are references to a series of parameters known as the "[Mössbauer parametra](https://books.google.com/books?id=7Wj8V1_27OIC&pg=PA217&dq=parametra&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhkbiV8LLQAhUL02MKHV8QA4cQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=parametra&f=false)," one is to a software tool called [ParaMetra](https://books.google.com/books?id=_K01OC0r5BwC&pg=PR17&dq=parametra&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhkbiV8LLQAhUL02MKHV8QA4cQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=parametra&f=false). Google Books evidence of any use in English of *parametra* as a simple plural form of *parameter* is exceedingly scant.

A [Google Books search for *parametroi*](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=parametroi&num=10) turns up several matches in Greek but nothing in English.

The standard plural form of *parameter* in English is (and as far as I can tell, always has been) *parameters*.

Answer (score 3):

As for the latter part of your question (*what is the source for the uncommon usage of 'parametra'*) - if indeed there is such a usage - my wild guess would be that it might have sounded "academic" or perhaps "proper Greek" to some ears, as in the case of *criteria*, but the truth is, as you point out yourself, that the correct plural form would be *parametroi*, *parametros* (parameter, that is) being a noun of the feminine gender, although *metron*, which - as has already been said - is one of the two words comprising the word *parametros*, is a noun of the neutral gender, and as such, becomes *metra* in the plural form (just like criterion becomes criteria, which btw answers the comment about surviving Greek plurals in English),

Comment: Do you know why the gender changes between "metro(n)" and "parametros"? That seems odd.

Comment: @suməlic Same applies to words such as _diametros_ (diameter), _perimetros_ (perimeter) and more, as opposed to _barometro_ (pronounced _varometro_, meaning barometer), _chronometro_ (chronometer), where the compound word has held on to the neutral gender (the plural form would hence be _barometra_, _chronometra_ etc.)

Comment: @suməlic ...Off hand, I can see two differences between these two groups of compound words: a) In the first group, there's actually just a preposition serving as a prefix (_para-, dia-, peri-_ etc.), whilst in the second group there are indeed two different stems (_baros_, meaning weight, or _chronos_, meaning time etc.) b) The words of the first group connote a somewhat abstract feature of a given item, whilst the words of the second group refer to actual instruments.

Answer (score 1):

***[Parameter/Parameters](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/parameter)*** are the correct terms, "Parametra" is not used in English.

> - A parameter is a limit. In mathematics a parameter is a constant in an equation, but parameter isn’t just for math anymore: now any system can have parameters that define its operation. You can set parameters for your class debate.
> - ***Parameter comes from a combination of the Greek word para-, meaning “beside,” and metron, meaning “measure.”*** The natural world sets certain parameters, like gravity and time. In court, the law defines the parameters of legal behavior. Parameter and perimeter are similar, but a perimeter is the physical distance around an object, while a parameter can contain or define something either physically or abstractly: before you marry, prepare for the parameters of monogamy.

Vocabulary.com

Usage examples:

> - *That makes it the heaviest observed elementary particle yet discovered, but within the parameters set by the Standard Model*. (Scientific America)
> - "*As hard as journalism is, at least you have parameters," she said*. (New York Times)
> - *Within those parameters, Ms. Gray played with color, creating an upbeat show reflecting London's mad, mad fashion world*. (New York Times)

Comment: Is there a correct Greek or Latin plural that can be used in English though?

Comment: @gktscrk - not that I know of, but I don't think so. Parameter is an old and long established  term : 
*1650s in geometry, from Modern Latin parameter (1630s), from Greek para- "beside, subsidiary"  + metron "measure"* http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=parameter

Comment: According to Google's Ngram, "lemmas" and "lemmata" battled it out till about 1910, when "lemmas" began to dominate.

Comment: @Airymouse: I think it's relevant though that "lemma" retains the non-nativized Greek suffix "ma," while "parameter" has been anglicized in the singular by lopping off the suffix -on and syllabifying the "r." Consider the word "problem": no one pluralizes it as "problemata."

Comment: I got it. No problemo.